# Каким редактором смотреть дописываемый файл?

Tags: ubuntu

Какой командой можно читать файл, в который постоянно идет запись, с возможностью использовать утилиту фильтрации `grep`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Вот, например:

```
tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log | grep "04"
```

Comment: `-f` отслеживает дескриптор файла. Чтобы отлавливать изменения по имени файла, можно `-F` использовать.

Answer (score 3):

У **less** есть возможность слежения и остановки обновляемого файла, со всем функционалом поиска и просмотра.

```
~$ less +F log_file
```